# How to use Yahoo with Hello.js

Tags: cordova, yahoo, yahoo-api, hello.js

I have figured out all of the other social networks for Hello.js. But cannot figure out yahoo.

My init call looks like this

```
hello.init({
    facebook: "xxx",
    twitter: "xxx",
    windows: "xxx",
    google: "xxx",
    linkedin: "xxx",
    yahoo: "xxx--"
}, {
    redirect_uri: http://www.example.com/redirect.html',
    oauth_proxy: "https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy"
});
```

My hello login is

```
hello.login("yahoo", {
    scope: "email"
}, function(auth, status) {
});
```

- I've got the heroku proxy app setup with 3 domains localhost:8080, local.com:8080 and example.com
- I've got yahoo developer setup with example.com as a domain and auth-server.herokuapp.com as another domain. Both unverified, (heroku unverified for obvious reasons)

Yahoo gives me this error "401 could not authenticate"

I'm testing from local.com:8080 and localhost:8080. I haven't tested within the phonegap app yet, but if this doesn't work I can't say that will work either.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Sean, i think you figured it out, i left an answer anyway, thanks. A

Answer (score 0):

"I've got yahoo developer setup with example.com as a domain and auth-server.herokuapp.com as another domain. Both unverified, (heroku unverified for obvious reasons)"

Only register the path your using as a redirect_url with the thirdparty, aka not the proxy service auth-server.herokuapp.com.

Did you register your app credentials with https://auth-server.herokuapp.com ?